# get click date in addEvent modal

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working on a fullcalendar project.
When I click on a day of my calendar it appeared a modal where you put the name of your event, the start date and end date.
The input for start and end date is a *datetime-local* and I was looking for a way that when you click on a day and the modal show up in my start input is already visualize the day.

This is my [modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUXXE.png) and, for example, when I click on 4th of April it appeared directly like this, without me having to put it manually: like this ->[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajte2.png).

I found online this solution to get the clicked date:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
                    alert(date.format('DD/MM/YYYY 08:00'));   //format i decide
                    
                },
```

But i dont know how to applied to my code to have it as input and not alert

---

I found also this way, I like it better because I can add the hour I want:

```
var startDateSelected = moment(event.startStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY 08:00:00");
var endDateSelected = moment(event.endStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY 17:30:00");
```

but still havent found a way to applied to my input datelocal-time

Comment: does anyone know how to help me? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found this solution:

```
select: function select(event, date) {              
    $('#addNewEvent').modal('show');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents',event._id);
    var now = new Date(event);
    document.getElementById('starts').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
    document.getElementById('ends').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
}
```

This is the function that open my modal and fecth the events from my database by ID
And the ID mention in *getElementById* are from my two datetime-local input

I hope someone can find it useful.
It refered to Fullcalendar v3 because that the version the template I'm using have